# Spark SQL similar to LISTAGG() within group OR GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement a function similar to redshift listagg() within group (order by x_column) but it is important to be in Spark SQL, the one here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220294/spark-dataframe-implementation-similar-to-oracles-listagg-function-unable-to) similar question but the answer is not no SQL.

My query on Redshift SQL would be:

```sql
select KEY,
listagg(CODE, '-') within group (order by DATE) as CODE
from demo_table
group by KEY
```

At this point it is not important the order by statement, only aggregating all the columns with the group by would be enough, I have tried with concat_ws and it does not work as expected

It won't work for me to have it on pyspark

| KEY | CODE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | PL | 11/1/2016 |
| 66 | PL | 12/1/2016 |
| 67 | JL | 12/1/2016 |
| 67 | JL | 10/1/2016 |
| 67 | PL | 9/1/2016 |
| 67 | PO | 8/1/2016 |
| 67 | JL | 12/1/2016 |
| 68 | PL | 11/1/2016 |
| 68 | JO | 11/1/2016 |

Desired output

| KEY | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 68 | JO - PL |
| 67 | JL - JL - PL - PO - JL |
| 68 | PL - JO |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark SQL replacement for MySQL's GROUP\_CONCAT aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysqls-group-concat-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 7):

[array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join) and [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html)

```
select 
 key, 
 array_join( -- concat the array
  collect_list(code), -- aggregate that collects the array of [code]
  ' - ' -- delimiter 
 )
from demo_table
group by KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will work. It includes order by as well. Please check.

```
spark.sql("""select key,max(code) 
             from ( select key,array_join(collect_list(code) over (partition by key order by to_date(date,'m/d/yyyy')),'-') code from view) 
             group by key""").show(100)
```

Comment: Please consider providing output of the source code in the answer, so users can correlate it with the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use "ORDER BY" and "COLLECT_LIST()" in Spark-SQL:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, "a3"),
(1, "a2"),
(4, "c"),
(1, "b2"),
(2, "b10"),
(4, "a"),
(2, "a1"),
(1, "a0"),
(3, "c"),
(4, "d")], ("k", "v"))

df.createOrReplaceTempView('source_df')

spark.sql("""
    SELECT t.k
        ,array_join(collect_list(t.v),'-') AS result_list            
    FROM (
        SELECT k
            ,v
        FROM source_df
        ORDER BY k,v
        ) t
    GROUP BY t.k
""").show()
```

Below is the output:

```bash
+---+-----------+
|  k|result_list|
+---+-----------+
|  1|a0-a2-a3-b2|
|  3|          c|
|  2|     a1-b10|
|  4|      a-c-d|
+---+-----------+
```