# Equivalent of LISTAGG() in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I am rewriting Redshift SQL in Spark SQL. Since LISTAGG() is not supported in Spark SQL, is there an equivalent function or workaround to implement this?

Redshift SQL:

```
SELECT
        dp_info_id,
        dp_type,
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(type,'-1') = 'Primary Name' 
            THEN LISTAGG(DISTINCT fir_name,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dp_info_id) 
            ELSE NULL
        END AS primary_first_name,
FROM
        dp_info c
GROUP BY
        dp_info,
        type,
        dp_type
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark SQL similar to LISTAGG() within group OR GROUP\_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380504/spark-sql-similar-to-listagg-within-group-or-group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of all values from the group by I guess you should use collect_set (https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/collect_list.html)